# I need to put a text on top of an image without CSS or JS

Tags: html, layout, browser, cross-browser

Is there a way I can place the text `<p>` on top of the image? without using css or javascript. just plain html. The reason being is this technique or approach will be use on older phones that do not support css or javascript. It also does not support "background" attribute.

http://jsbin.com/aroxit/2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS is the only way to do this. No other HTML options give you the ability to position items on top of each other. The only other alternative is to set the text server-side and re-generate the image with the text in the image, just like icanhascheezburger does.

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of CSS or JS, this is not possible. The position or display of HTML elements cannot be affected by HTML alone.

Answer (score 0):

no - do it server side or don't worry about it - not all browsers need to look the same. There is a calculation you need to do  - is this going to get enough traffic from these devices to justify spending time fixing this 'problem'. As long as it is usable in the device it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Add the image as a background image to a single cell table and then insert another table in the td tag where your text can reside.